# Rails dropdown, how the selection of a field can trigger another to appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

So I have a form to create in Ruby on Rails, and I got to make appear a second dropdown menu once the first has been selected.

This is the requirement for the homework: "Display a DropDown Selector listing all clients (Table Customers), only one client can be selected at a time. As soon as the selection is made, the change triggers the action of the building selection field of the form - next step 2"

Here is the code of my views/intervention/intervention.html.erb:

```
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center offset-md-3 ">
        <%= collection_select(:intervention, :customer_id, Customer.order(:full_name_company_contact), :id, :full_name_company_contact, {prompt: 'Select a customer'}) %>
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center text-blue offset-md-3">
        <%= collection_select(:intervention, :building_id, Building.order(:id), :id, :id, {prompt: 'Select a building'}) %> 
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center text-blue offset-md-3">
        <%= collection_select(:intervention, :battery_id, Battery.order(:building_id), :id, :building_id, {prompt: 'Select a battery'}) %> 
    </div><br><br>
    
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center text-blue offset-md-3">
        <%= collection_select(:intervention, :column_id, Column.order(:battery_id), :id, :battery_id, {prompt: 'Select a column'})  %>
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center text-blue offset-md-3">
        <%= collection_select(:intervention, :elevator_id, Elevator.order(:column_id), :id, :column_id, {prompt: 'Select an elevator'}) %>
    </div><br><br>
    
    <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto text-center text-blue offset-md-3">
        <%= collection_select(:intervention, :employee_id, Employee.order(:first_name), :id, :first_name, {prompt: 'Select an employee'}) %>
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        Description
            <textarea maxlength="1000" rows="8" class="form-control" name="intervention[description]" id="intervention:message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="btn-primary btn-lg mt-12" id="submitBtn"> Submit </button>
        </div>
    </div>


</fieldset>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to show/hide dropdowns

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#customer_id').on(change, function(){
           $('#building_id').show();
       });
        
    });
```